# Could not build Objective-C module 'SwipeCellKit'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I want to integrate this into my app

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwipeCellKit

so I add this line 
`pod 'SwipeCellKit'`
into my pod file and run `pod install`

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'ListHue' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SwipeCellKit'

end
```

After installed, I got these message

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Realm (3.7.4)
Using RealmSwift (3.7.4)
Using SwipeCellKit (2.4.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 3 total pods installed.
```

I'm not sure why when I tried to import it XCode was yelling at me.

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the entire podFile

Comment: Yes, I did. It is in the post.

Comment: tried to put **use_frameworks!** before target

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dBdwziP.png

Comment: Can you try **pod 'SwipeCellKit', :git => 'https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.git', :branch => 'swift_4.2'** , copy it from here https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwipeCellKit

Comment: Try your first suggestion is not working.

Comment: I'm going to try to remove all my pods related items and re-install everything.